# Learning Django as an experienced ASP.NET developer

Tags: django

I am quite aware of the MVC concept, though I have never developed anything bigger in ASP.NET MVC, but I have been developing ASP.NET pages for years now.

So is there any good tutorial or even better: a book that is suitable for an ASP.NET developer and does comparisons? Especially I am looking for information on Django reusability/how to deal with components, etc.

Comment: I'm doing both throughout my week, and they are quite a bit different, you really just have to stand up a vm, and live the lifestyle with the book a bit. I'm using ubuntu and gedit to do my django work, its quite a breath of fresh air, but there are hardly any comparisons.

Comment: DevelopingChris makes a good point. Best way to learn it is with a linux distro (or osx if you like) and a good editor. Komodo Edit is also available for Linux, and is a little more IDEish (making the assumption you're using visual studio for asp.net and like IDEs). I'd suggest you avoid django/python on windows. It just makes life more difficult. Using a VM is far easier.

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of your background, if you want to learn DJango, try the free online  [Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of anything that will specifically compare ASP.NET code to Django/Python. There are a bunch of good books though. [Practical Django Projects](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599969) 2nd Edition by James Bennett is an excellent book. It has a couple of example applications you can build.

There's also [Pro Django](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210478) by Marty Alchin that really gets into some of the guts of Django. There isn't any "tutorial" kind of information here. It's more just an extension of the documentation.

Both of these books talk some about reusability in Django, but they don't dwell on it specifically that much. One of Django's design goals has been to keep things modular and reusable. Because of this, there are a lot of mostly plug and play apps that you can drop into your project.

Once you get a little bit familiar with how Django works, you should check out [Virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) to manage each of your projects. It helps out a ton.